# Get appendRow() in GAS to copy border-style

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When I call appenRow() in GAS the new row has the backgroundcolor and textcolor of the row above but NOT the border. How can I keep my border style for appended rows?

Comment: You can use copyTo() there several different flavors take a look at the range class in the documentation.

Comment: Would it be possible to share the sheet with dummy data in it along with the script that you're currently using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a sample that appends a row and copies the format from previous rows (in this example, each row has 3 cells with data and formatting, in columns A-B-C, but you can change it according to how your sheet is):

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var gridId = sheet.getSheetId();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var column = 1; // Change if necessary according to your sheet
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var range = sheet.getRange(lastRow, column, 1, lastColumn);
  sheet.appendRow(["data1","data2","data3"]) // Change according to your sheet
  range.copyFormatToRange(gridId, column, lastColumn, lastRow + 1, lastRow + 1)
}
```

The function to notice here is [copyFormatToRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyFormatToRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)), which copies all formatting properties from one range to a given location (in this case, to the appended row).

I hope this is of any help.